# How to create a dialog window to choose a file path

Tags: c++, qt

I'm new to qt, and I have a button, if I click on it I want to get a dialog box to choose a path where I want to save a file. My question is, how could I create this kind of dialog box, which returns with a string of the path? I use linux, if it matters with qt:)

ps.: I use only gedit, so I'd like to solve it that way. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the answer by @Muckle_ewe, there is a the static  function QFileDialog::getSaveFileName, which will present the standard open / save file dialog and allow the user to both select the path and input a name for the file.

It's definition is this: -

```
QString QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(QWidget * parent = 0, const QString & caption = QString(), const QString & dir = QString(), const QString & filter = QString(), QString * selectedFilter = 0, Options options = 0)
```

An example of its usage is: -

```
QString fileName = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this, tr("Save File"),
                       "/home/untitled.png",
                       tr("Images (*.png *.xpm *.jpg)"));
```

As the docs state,

> This is a convenience static function that will return a file name
>   selected by the user. The file does not have to exist.

Answer (score 2):

Use QFileDialog which has several useful static member functions including

```
QString myDir = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory();
```

which returns a directory that you select. I think that is what you want, see the docmentation here

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qfiledialog.html

Comment: Thank you! I take a look :)